# Creating new sheet in XL

Tags: java, excel

Below code will create a sheet say: `Sheet1`, but when it creates a another sheet it is overwriting I guess, I need it to retain the existing one `sheet1` and create a new sheet say `sheet2`. Help me out.

```
public static String xl_write(String xl_res, String [][] xData,int sheet_no, int row_count) {

    //System.out.println("Sheet no:" +sheet_no);
    System.out.println("row count:" + row_count);
    //System.out.println("xdata:" +xData[i][j]);
    System.out.println("write res:" +xl_res);

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

    XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet("TestResult " + sheet_no);

    for(int i=0;i<=row_count;i++) {
        XSSFRow wr = ws.createRow(i);

        for(int j=0;j<=4;j++){

            System.out.println("I:" +i);
            System.out.println("J:" +j);
            System.out.println("xdata:" +xData);
            System.out.println("xdata:" +xData [i] [j]);

            XSSFCell wc = wr.createCell(j);
            wc.setCellValue(xData[i][j]);
        }
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(xl_res);
        wb.write(fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return xData;
    return xl_res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each and every time method is called you are creating an new instance of XSSFWorkbook. So, your code is creating a workbook and then you are saying to create a sheet so it is again creating sheet in new workbook.

It's not overriding you are creating Workbook every time whenever method is being called.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how many sheets exist with

```
int getNumberOfSheets()
```

Look [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) to find the API.

If you try:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
int num = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
```

you can increase num by `num++;` and create the new sheet with your new num.

Comment: thanks guys.....
@Kulbhushan Singh.....Yes i can't remove this instance XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();. b'c i am using the wb for wb.createSheet("TestResult " + sheet_no);.....